# Confusion on Creating New Table EF Code-First One to Many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am creating a EF Code-First MVC application.  When I first started, I made the database first with the tables that I knew I would need.  Now I have come across a situation where I need to add another table.  In the past I usually do EF Database-First and just create the table in SSMS and update my EDMX, but I want to expand my knowledge and start doing projects Code-First.

So the table that I need to create is called `Event` and that table will be linked to another table that is already created.. called `ApplicantInformation`.

The relationship is that 1 Event can have many Applicant Information - `Event 1 ... * ApplicantInformation`.

Here is how I have created my `Event` class:

```
public class Event
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my `ApplicantInformation` class:

```
[Table("ApplicantInformation")]
public partial class ApplicantInformation
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public ApplicantInformation()
    {
        Events = new HashSet<Event>();
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int City { get; set; }

    public int State { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateEntered { get; set; }
    public int EventId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EventId")]
    public Event Event { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

When I `add-migration` I see this:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Events",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    EventName = c.String(),
                    Active = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    ApplicantInformation_ID = c.Int(), // where does this come from?
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.ApplicantInformation", t => t.ApplicantInformation_ID) // where did ApplicantInformation_ID come from?
            .Index(t => t.ApplicantInformation_ID); // again, where did this property come from?

        AddColumn("dbo.ApplicantInformation", "EventId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        CreateIndex("dbo.ApplicantInformation", "EventId");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.ApplicantInformation", "EventId", "dbo.Events", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
        DropColumn("dbo.ApplicantInformation", "CareerEvent");
    }
```

My question (if you didn't read the comments), is where did `ApplicantInformation_ID` come from?  I obviously didn't put that property in my `Event` class?

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

So I can just get rid of the `ICollection<Event>` and the constructor in my `ApplicantInformation` class and it will still be a one to many relationship?

```
public class Event
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Event()
    {
        ApplicantInformations = new HashSet<ApplicantInformation>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicantInformation> ApplicantInformations { get; set; }
}

[Table("ApplicantInformation")]
public partial class ApplicantInformation
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int City { get; set; }

    public int State { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateEntered { get; set; }
    public int EventId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EventId")]
    public Event Event { get; set; }
}
```

Migration:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Events",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    EventName = c.String(),
                    Active = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        AddColumn("dbo.ApplicantInformation", "EventId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        CreateIndex("dbo.ApplicantInformation", "EventId");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.ApplicantInformation", "EventId", "dbo.Events", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
        DropColumn("dbo.ApplicantInformation", "CareerEvent");
    }
```

Comment: It comes (by convention) from `public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }` navigation property of the `ApplicantInformation` entity. Any reason for adding that property there? Because it defines another relation - `ApplicantInformation 1 ... * Event`.

Comment: @IvanStoev the reason I added that was because I have other tables that I originally created in the db first and then when I chose to use EF Code-First, and brought the tables over.. I have classes that use that line.. for example.. in one of my other classes I have `public virtual ICollection<ApplicantInformation> ApplicantInformations { get; set; }` because this other table is related to the ApplicantInformations table

Comment: see my update for what I have corrected

Comment: I understand, but then you've probably put the wrong collection on the wrong place. The rule is simple - you put the collection navigation property at *one* side and reference navigation property at *many* side. The way you described the desired relationship, the collection should be `public ICollection<ApplicantInformation> Applicants { get; set; }` inside the `Event` class.

Comment: @IvanStoev Oh my.. you're absolutely right.. I did put the collection in the wrong place.. so I edited my question with an update on how my classes look now.  Look okay?

Comment: Now it's perfect :)

Comment: @IvanStoev I've even updated the migration.  Quick question.. is the `[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]` section needed? The only reason I copied it was because of my auto-generated classes having them

Comment: @IvanStoev if you want to put an answer down I will accept it.  I don't want to close this question because I want to use it as reference for other projects in the future, plus maybe someone else will experience this.

Comment: The attribute is not needed, except you have requirement to pass the Code Analysis rules :) What about answering, glad it helped you and appreciate the proposal for earning some points, but it's pretty basic and is covered by any EF tutorial. May be the next time when you have some tricky issue :) You could post a self answer though. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Ivan in the comment section:

> I understand, but then you've probably put the wrong collection on the wrong place. The rule is simple - you put the collection navigation property at one side and reference navigation property at many side. The way you described the desired relationship, the collection should be public ICollection Applicants { get; set; } inside the Event class.

This was exactly my problem.